# How to fix java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config?

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to generate java code from `swagger.json` using `swagger-codegen-cli.jar` but I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config!
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:763)
        at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:299)
        at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
```

The command I'm trying to run is the following:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i swagger.json -l java -c java-config.json -o api-client
```

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47301891/swagger-3-0-0-codegen-failed-java-lang-runtimeexception-missing-swagger-input-o) and show your swagger.json file

Comment: Sorry can't share my swagger.json

Comment: What version of Swagger Codegen do you use (`java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar version`)? Is your swagger.json file `swagger: '2.0'` or `openapi: 3.0.0`?

Comment: the swagger-codegen-cli.json I cloned from master branch https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen, I don't know which version the jar corresponds to, as for the swagger.json it's openapi: 3.0.1

Comment: @Helen I think the master branch corresponds to 2.X version of Swagger Codegen, I'm cloning from 3.0.0 branch to try it

Comment: with git clone from master version reported is 2.4.33-SNAPSHOT (yes, a few years later June 2023)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You are using Swagger Codegen 2.x which does not support OpenAPI 3.0.

You need to use **Swagger Codegen 3.x** instead. You can download the latest 3.x CLI JAR from Maven Central:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.codegen.v3/swagger-codegen-cli

Here's a direct link to v. 3.0.20 CLI (the latest version as of the time of writing):
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/codegen/v3/swagger-codegen-cli/3.0.20/swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.20.jar

Or if you prefer to build the codegen from the source code, version 3 is in the `3.0.0` branch:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/3.0.0

Comment: but if you are using the swagger codegen, why are you listing the JAR depedency? the official documentation says you need to list it in the pom.xml as a plugin? Is there something I don't understand here?

Comment: @ennth There are many ways to run Swagger Codegen: as a Maven plugin, as a CLI tool, as a Docker image, etc. This Q&A is about CLI specifically.

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen;
cd swagger-codegen;
git checkout 3.0.0;`