# How to fix missing swagger input or config?

Tags: swagger-codegen

I am facing issue while generating code via swagger cli using csharp-dotnet2 template.
It is almost same issue as mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62576586/how-to-fix-java-lang-runtimeexception-missing-swagger-input-or-config)

I am able to generate the code from https://editor.swagger.io/
but when I am using swagger cli as i need to modify the template
I have tried generating code with different version of swagger and currently using swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.27.jar. but it is not working.

Please check attached screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4O2L.png)

Command

```
java -cp swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.27.jar io.swagger.codegen.Codegen -i vendor.yaml -l csharp-dotnet2 -o outputdir.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command instead:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.27.jar generate -i vendor.yaml -l csharp-dotnet2 -o outputdir
```